# What are typical numbers for chakra reserves and regeneration times in Naruto?

Tags: naruto

The Naruto franchise has been going on for long enough now that it should be possible to get some actual numerical values on chakra reserves and how much chakra is regenerated over time. Before I start trying to work this out using various incidents from the anime, I'd like to know if there are any pre-existing "studies" or creator statements regarding this subject?

Comment: As far as I'm aware of it, there's no numbers period. People either do long rests, in which we don't have numbers, or shortly rest and exhaust themselves. Moreover, we don't have a reserve number anywhere in the series.

Comment: I figured as much, but didn't want to assume. I'll have to work it out for myself. I'm thinking a high total pool that regenerates slowly, and a lower current pool which fills from the total pool at a fast rate. So it allows for the short rest to exhaustion scenarios while also allowing the "Kakashi was hospitalised for a week due to chakra depletion" situation.

Comment: What do you mean by numerical value on chakra reserves?

Comment: Kakashi says a few times that Naruto has 4 times as much chakra as him. I'm after a numerical representation of that. Say, Kakashi with 100 units of chakra compared to Naruto's 400.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the Shinobi, I mean if they strain their chakra reserves by doing a bunch of exercises, in theory their reserves will grow. Regeneration time depends on the time you rest. If you're asleep you have a faster revival rate, but if you just sit still you'll have a slower revival rate, and if you're active (even if you are not using chakra) you'll have an even slower revival rate.